# Averageifs constraint using wildcard

Tags: excel

This should be a pretty simple task but I for the life of me cannot figure out why its not working

I am trying to use the following

```
=AVERAGEIFS($L$50:$L$600,$A$50:$A$600,"*6:00:00 AM")
```

The constraint is referencing the following cell

```
5/23/2016  6:00:00 AM
```

I have confirmed that there are no zeros in L and as proof of this the function works the second I change the constraint to "5/23/2016  6:00:00 AM"

Is this a simple mistake that I have been wasting my time on?

**Edit**

I tried the following but am getting the same #VALUE!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($L$50:$L$600)*(TIME(HOUR($A$50:$A$600),MINUTE($A$50:$A$600),SECOND($A$50:$A$600))=TIME(6,0,0)))/SUMPRODUCT(1*(TIME(HOUR($A$50:$A$600),MINUTE($A$50:$A$600),SECOND($A$50:$A$600))=TIME(6,0,0)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that to Excel Date/Time is a number like 42067.678 that has a number mask applied to display what you see. so what you want is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($L$50:$L$600)*(TIME(HOUR($A$50:$A$600),MINUTE($A$50:$A$600),SECOND($A$50:$A$600))=TIME(6,0,0)))/SUMPRODUCT(1*(TIME(HOUR($A$50:$A$600),MINUTE($A$50:$A$600),SECOND($A$50:$A$600))=TIME(6,0,0)))
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense but unless I am misunderstanding the math in there this will not give me an average of the values found in L when A has 6:00:00.

Comment: @Josh yeah I did the sum a forgot the count on the divide.  See edit.  You may need to refresh the sheet.

Comment: Getting a #Value!
looking into it

Comment: If you are getting #Value the most likely either column L or column A in those ranges has a text or error value.  Check your dates and insure that they are true dates and not text that look like dates. @Josh

Comment: Got it, I had some random characters hanging out. How hard would it be to add a second constraint to this function?

Answer (score 1):

This array-entered formula should do the trick.  Enter the formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.

**EDIT:** Edit'd as original formula gave incorrect answer

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(Times,1) = TIME(6,0,0),Range_To_Avg))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
=AVERAGEIFS($L$50:$L$600,$A$50:$A$600,"6:00:00 AM")
```

I think your issue is the star in front of the time.

EDIT: Misunderstood the question ;)

My solution is to copy the values to text before performing operation, this will allow the function to work correctly.

Comment: The * is a wildcard character which is the whole point of the question.

Comment: That is correct, in my example yesterdays date will not be the only date that exists for the 6:00:00 AM slot